# Does the $\sum_{k}$ remain after differentiating $log(\frac{\sum_{k}W_{ik}H_{kj}}{const.})$ wrt $H_{kj}$? and why?

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus

I would like to differentiate this equation where $W_{ik}$ and $H_{kj}$ are matrix:

$0  = \sum_{ij}(log(\frac{\sum_{k}W_{ik}H_{kj}}{const.}))$ wrt $H_{kj}$

After applying chain rule to log:

$0 = \sum_{ij}(\frac{const.}{\sum_{k}W_{ik}H_{kj}})(\frac{\sum_{k}W_{ik}}{const.})$

I wonder for the term $\frac{\sum_{k}W_{ik}}{const.}$, the $\sum_{k}$ should be remained?

What I am confused is: since $H_{kj}$ is already differentiated, $W_{ik}$ can't do matrix multiplication and sum may be not required anymore. But in another way, the final answer is zero. If $W_{ik}$ doesn't take sum, the final answer will be vector (not zero). I am not sure what is right. May someone explain the reason about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the summation symbols and use straight matrix notation.

Let $\,\beta = \tfrac{1}{{\rm const.}},\,$ then the differential and gradient of the function can be calculated as 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= 1:\log(\beta WH) \cr
d\phi &= 1:d\log(\beta WH)
  = 1:\frac{\beta W\,dH}{\beta WH}
  = W^T\Big(\frac{1}{WH}\Big):dH \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial H} &= W^T\Big(\frac{1}{WH}\Big) \cr
}$$
where the dimensions of the variables are:
 $W\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n},\,$
 $H\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times p},\,$
 $1\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times p},\,$ and 
 $\phi\in{\mathbb R}$.

Further, $\log(X)$ and $\frac{1}{X}$ are taken to be element-wise operations, and a colon has been used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)}$$

Comment: May I ask how do you know it should start from $\phi = 1:\log(\beta WH)$? I mean why do you define $\phi$ as a product of $1$ and $\log(\beta WH)$? I am not sure I understand the importance of $1$.

Comment: @Jan: i think $\mathbf{1}$ is all-ones vector such that the Frobenius product $\mathbf{1}: \log\left(\beta \mathbf{W} \mathbf{H} \right) = \sum_{i,j} \log\left( \left[WH\right]_{i,j} \right)$ ... if this makes sense to you and if greg approves my interpretation

Comment: @user550103 Your explanation is exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed indices confuse. $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial H_{uv}}\sum_{i,j}\log\frac{\sum_k W_{ik} H_{kj}}{\text{const.}} = \sum_i\frac{W_{iu}}{\sum_k W_{ik} H_{kv}}$.