# Is $\sum\limits_k \frac{W_{ik} H_{kj}}{\sum\limits_k W_{ik} H_{kj}}$ = 1?

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, matrix-equations

I derive an equation and get the term $\sum\limits_k \frac{W_{ik} H_{kj}}{\sum\limits_k W_{ik} H_{kj}}$. I think this term is equal to 1 because

Proof:

$\sum\limits_k \frac{W_{ik} H_{kj}}{(\sum\limits_k W_{ik} H_{kj})_{ij}} = \frac{1}{(\sum\limits_k W_{ik} H_{kj})_{ij}} \times \sum\limits_k W_{ik} H_{kj} = 1$

where $W$ and $H$ are matrices with dimension $i \times k$ and $k \times j$, respectively

I just wonder is this proof correct?

Comment: Your notations are horrendous. First, what is $(\Sigma_k W_{ik} H_{kj})_{ij}$? Second, why do you use the same index in the outer sum and in the inner sum? Third, the symbol for sums is `\sum`, not `\Sigma`. What is right however is that $$\sum_k \frac{W_{ik} H_{kj}}{\sum\limits_\ell W_{i\ell} H_{\ell j}}=\frac1{\sum\limits_\ell W_{i\ell} H_{\ell j}}\sum_k W_{ik} H_{kj}=1$$

Comment: @Did: Looks like an answer to me?

Comment: @joriki Free to use, anyway.

Comment: @Did if you may answer below, I would accept it. Sorry for `\sum` and `\Sigma`. I used the same index because they are the same matrix. But I think I get your point.

Comment: This "mess of indices" is already seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882029/does-the-sum-k-remain-after-differentiating-log-frac-sum-kw-ikh-kj/). It _is_ the source of problems.

Comment: @metamorphy No it is not seen there.